# Grabbing values between quotation marks and replacing it enclosed inside some command

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I am sure this has been asked before, but I am not sure how to search for the exact case.

How do I use regex to search/replace for whatever is inside double quotes, such as:

```
"Sample text"
```

and replace it with:

```
\command{Sample text}
```

where "Sample text" can be anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what tool/language you're using, but in general:

```
Search: "(.*?)"
Replace: \\command{$1}
```

This works by capturing (in group 1) the text inside quotes and using a back reference to that group in the replacement.

Your tool/language may use backslash instead of dollar to indicate the group number, ie try `\\command{\1}` instead if the above doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you. I was working in Notepad++ and your answer worked like a charm.

Comment: @black are the nested quoted escapes? If so how? Can you give an example? FYI you can use backticks in comments to wrap text you want displayed as "code".

Comment: For example `"This quote which involves "inner quotes," and possibly even more nested quotes."` to `\command{This quote which involves \command{inner quotes,} and possibly even more nested quotes.}`

Comment: Try removing the question mark from the search regex, ie `"(.*)"`